# Looking for: Transparent HTTP Proxy “driver” for windows

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, software-rec, http

I have a windows computer inside a network where I have to use an HTTP proxy to access the internet.

Is it possible to install a program (or configure windows) in a way that I do not have to set the proxy in every single program?

So that the installed program or driver just forwards the traffic in a transparent way to the HTTP server (HTTP company proxy)?

Answer (score 0):

There are several products which can do this, intercept outbound connections made by apps and divert them via a proxy.

One example of this is [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com) which supports SOCKS and also CONNECT tunneling via an http proxy.

Another is the [OpenText SOCKS client](https://www.opentext.com/what-we-do/products/specialty-technologies/connectivity/socks-client) which uses the SOCKS protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Win2Socks](https://win2socks.com), it supports TCP & UDP.